# ECDSA sign with HSM and verify in Java/Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, signature, public-key, ecdsa

I have a public key and a signature generated from HSM using CryptokiEx and I need to verify the signature in Java, but have some difficulties doing so.

Signature is signed in HSM

```
byte[] signature = null;
LongRef signLen = new LongRef();

CryptokiEx.C_SignInit(hSession, signMech, hPrivateKey);

/* determine the length of the signature */
CryptokiEx.C_Sign(hSession, hash, hashLen, null, signLen);

signature = new byte[(int) signLen.value];

CryptokiEx.C_Sign(hSession, hash, hashLen, signature, signLen);
```

Output

```
public key: 030F92CF7082006E46ADBB7C51AD12435110595C59C45518E35C794AD6578D4FEE
private key: 00BF9044CED80C5E358F3673C998417A564E52B8837C21FD5DA6DFA8E506983B03
signature: 7531DDE88945CC2431F69C237B7A5A52D042E44CFBE9FF2AC8C821E6EC507EC0ABC6AD1909A7C571E1C504261AEE5B92B3061D9AD7F921738C79806584CFD358
message hash: 68656c6c6f20776f726c64
```

Public key is constructed

```
fun constructPublicKey(compressedPKStr: String) :ECPublicKey {
    var publicKeyStr = compressedToUncompressed(compressedPKStr).toHex()
    publicKeyStr = publicKeyStr.substring(2)
    val kf: KeyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC")
    val pubKeyX = publicKeyStr.substring(0, publicKeyStr.length / 2)
    val pubKeyY = publicKeyStr.substring(publicKeyStr.length / 2)
    val x: ByteArray = pubKeyX.hexToByteArray()
    val y: ByteArray = pubKeyY.hexToByteArray()
    val w = ECPoint(BigInteger(1, x), BigInteger(1, y))
    return kf.generatePublic(ECPublicKeySpec(w, ecParameterSpecForCurve("secp256k1"))) as ECPublicKey
}

@Throws(NoSuchAlgorithmException::class, InvalidParameterSpecException::class)
fun ecParameterSpecForCurve(curveName: String?): ECParameterSpec {
    val params = AlgorithmParameters.getInstance("EC")
    params.init(ECGenParameterSpec(curveName))
    return params.getParameterSpec(ECParameterSpec::class.java)
}

fun compressedToUncompressed(compressedPKStr: String) :ByteArray {
    val compKey = compressedPKStr.hexToByteArray()
    var SPEC = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("secp256k1")
    val point = SPEC.curve.decodePoint(compKey)
    val x: ByteArray = point.xCoord.encoded
    val y: ByteArray = point.yCoord.encoded
    // concat 0x04, x, and y, make sure x and y has 32-bytes:
    // 0x04 to indicate uncompressed PK
    return concat(byteArrayOf(0x04), x, y)
}
```

Signature is converted to ASN.1 DER format

```
@Throws(NumberFormatException::class)
fun byteToBin(byte: Byte): String {
    val number = java.lang.Byte.toUnsignedInt(byte)
    val s2 = String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(number)).replace(' ', '0')
    return s2
}

fun constructSignature(signatureStr: String) :ByteArray {
    val signatureR = signatureStr.substring(0, signatureStr.length / 2)
    val signatureS = signatureStr.substring(signatureStr.length / 2)
    var signatureRData = signatureR.hexToByteArray()
    val firstRByteBin = byteToBin(signatureRData[0])
    if (firstRByteBin.first() == '1') {
        signatureRData = concat(byteArrayOf(0x00), signatureRData)
    }
    var signatureSData = signatureS.hexToByteArray()
    val firstSByteBin = byteToBin(signatureSData[0])
    if (firstSByteBin.first() == '1') {
        signatureSData = concat(byteArrayOf(0x00), signatureSData)
    }
    val b2 = signatureRData.size
    val b3 = signatureSData.size
    val b1 = b2 + b3 + 4
    return concat(byteArrayOf(0x30, b1.toByte(), 0x02, b2.toByte()), signatureRData, byteArrayOf(0x02, b3.toByte()), signatureSData)
}
```

Verify the signature but result is false

```
val testBytes = "68656c6c6f20776f726c64".hexToByteArray()

val publicKeyStr = "030F92CF7082006E46ADBB7C51AD12435110595C59C45518E35C794AD6578D4FEE"
val publicKey = constructPublicKey(publicKeyStr)

val signatureStr = "7531DDE88945CC2431F69C237B7A5A52D042E44CFBE9FF2AC8C821E6EC507EC0ABC6AD1909A7C571E1C504261AEE5B92B3061D9AD7F921738C79806584CFD358"
val signatureData = constructSignature(signatureStr)

val signature: Signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA")

signature.initVerify(publicKey)

signature.update(testBytes)

signature.verify(signatureData)
```

Do you have an idea where I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out where it's wrong. The message needs to be hashed using SHA256 before signing

```
MessageDigest digest = null;
try {
    digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    System.out.println("Something is wrong");
}
byte[] hash = digest.digest(dataBytes);

CryptokiEx.C_Sign(hSession, hash, hashLen, signature, signLen);
```